# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null" during API unit test with react 0.0.0-experimental-0eea57724

Tags: reactjs

After upgrading react & react-dom versions from `0.0.0-experimental-6a589ad71` to `0.0.0-experimental-0eea57724`, one of my API unit tests started breaking and this version bump is the only change that was made. I don't understand why because the unit test only tests a server-side API that does not use React in any way.

```
C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:3964
      var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:3964:26)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:4115:31)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24276:9)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24264:7)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24252:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:26317:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:26264:14)
    at C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:26073:9
    at workLoop (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:253:34)
    at flushWork (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:226:14)
    at Immediate.performWorkUntilDeadline (C:\Users\markj\workspace\myapp\packages\website\node_modules\react-dom\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:516:21)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deeply nested in my test was a reference to an object that had JSX as the value of a property.

Comment: Since you solved the problem, you can click the tick to accept this answer.

Comment: @Scruffy it said i had to wait 2 days before it would let me do that :)